# Unidentified JS file on desktop

Tags: malware

I noticed just then an unidentified file with a `.js` extension on my desktop. I double-clicked it before thinking about it and it opened as text with Pluma (my default text editor). Should I be concerned? I am attaching an image of part of the code.

Here is part of the code

```
Jma,Lma,d_,e_,Mma,Nma,Oma,h_,Pma,Qma,Rma,Sma,i_,g_,k_,l_,m_,n_,o_,p_,q_,r_,s_,t_,u_,v_,Tma,w_,Uma,x_,y_,A_,z_,B_,C_,D_,E_,F_,G_,H_,Vma,Wma,I_,Xma,Yma,J_,Zma,K_,L_,M_,$ma,N_,O_,P_,Q_,ana,bna,dna,ena,T_,U_,R_,cna,S_,fna,V_,W_,gna,X_,Z_,Y_,$_,a0,hna,b0,c0,jna,d0,lna,f0,mna,nna,g0,h0,i0,ona,j0,pna,k0,m0,rna,n0,o0,p0,q0,r0,s0,t0,u0,v0,una,z0,B0,C0,aa,ha,D0,Kaa,Rc,Ma,faa;ca=function(a){return function(){return aa[a].apply(this,arguments)}};
g.da=function(a,b){return aa[a]=b};
ea=function(a){var b=0;return function(){return b<a.length?{done:!1,value:a[b++]}:{done:!0}}};
g.p=function(a){var b="undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.iterator&&a[Symbol.iterator];return b?b.call(a):{next:ea(a)}};
g.fa=function(a){if(!(a instanceof Array)){a=g.p(a);for(var b,c=[];!(b=a.next()).done;)c.push(b.value);a=c}return a};
g.r=function(a,b){a.prototype=ha(b.prototype);a.prototype.constructor=a;if(ia)ia(a,b);else for(var c in b)if("prototype"!=c)if(Object.defineProperties){var d=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b,c);d&&Object.defineProperty(a,c,d)}else a[c]=b[c];a.yb=b.prototype};
ma=function(a,b){if(b){for(var c=ka,d=a.split("."),e=0;e<d.length-1;e++){var f=d[e];f in c||(c[f]={});c=c[f]}d=d[d.length-1];e=c[d];f=b(e);f!=e&&null!=f&&la(c,d,{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:f})}};
na=function(){na=function(){};
```

This is a screenshot of the code:

> [image: Screenshot of the code]

Comment: Minified JS tends to be used a lot in malware. Try running the file through VirusTotal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest booting a live system, installing and updating `clamav`and scanning the system/file in question.